# How can I find out what my concurrent requests are?

Tags: apex, governorlimits

Is there a way to report/query on what my concurrent/long running requests are?

Looking at [this link](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/engineering/2013/05/force-com-concurrent-request-limits.html) I would like to be review my org and see if there are any processes getting close to, if not going over, the 5 second limit.

Comment: Are you trying to figure this out from *within context*? If so, any measures you take to assess will add concurrent requests. If you are trying to figure it out from a system perspective, I don't think it's possible. If it is possible, it will probably take some really creative engineering.

Comment: Good question, I certainly don't want to add anything to the context. I guess I am assuming that Salesforce can measure it otherwise they wouldn't be able to enforce it, so is this something we can query and be more proactive about finding long running processes rather than wait for the limit to be hit?

Comment: Hmm so you want to be able to kill the process if that's the case? I've never actually seen the limit that gets thrown for this, but you could implement some sort of kill switch if you're over 8-9 seconds in the current context.

Comment: --If you have frameworks/patterns implemented, you could instrument your code to write to a `log__c` the #CPUmilliseconds your transactions are taking and then do reports after the fact to discover who the miscreants are - think of this as early warning/"connecting the dots" system before a Limits failure occurs